# How can I pass a variable into a lambda function? Dynamic Lambda functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, lambda, oop

In the last line, how can I ensure that the "this" i'm referring to is the instantiated k8rModal object and NOT the object running the function?

For other items in the future I'll need to dynamically construct lambda functions as well. Is that possible WITHOUT a global variable?

```
function k8rModal(DOMnamespace){
    var _ = this._ = DOMnamespace+"_"; // for DOM namespacing

    this.tightWrap=1;

    $('body').prepend('<div id="'+_+'stage"></div>');
    this.stage = stage = $('#'+_+'stage');
    stage.css({
        'display':'none',
        'width':'100%',
        'height':'100%',
        'color':'#333'
    });

    $('body').append('<div id="'+_+'slate"></div>');
    this.slate = slate = $('#'+_+'slate');
    slate.css({
        'display':'none',
        'width':'640px',
        'height':'480px',
        'color':'#eee'
    });

    $('body').delegate('.'+_+'caller','click',function(){
        /* this... but not, this? */.appear();
    });
}

k8rModal.prototype.appear = function(){
    //make the modal box appear
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `this` everywhere, just use `var that = this;` at the top of your function and use `that` from then on. So then in other scopes, they can still use their own `this` but still reference the higher `this` as `that`.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use variable reference to refer to the proper object as @ianpgall suggested, another possibility is to use jQuery's event data for this purpose.

```
$('body').delegate('.'+_+'caller','click', {k8r: this}, function(event){
    event.data.k8r.appear();
});
```

---

Or if you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, you should probably be using `.on()` instead.j

```
$('body').on('click', '.'+_+'caller', {k8r: this}, function(event){
    event.data.k8r.appear();
});
```

---

- [docs for jQuery's `event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)
- [docs for jQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)